# Why Restsharp request object won't be renewed in every call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, restsharp

This is my RestClientService :

```
public class RestClientService : IRestClientService
{
    protected readonly RestClient _restClient;
    protected readonly RestRequest _restRequest;

    public RestClientService()
    {
        _restClient = new RestClient();
        _restRequest = new RestRequest();
    }

    public async Task<MessageDTO> SendComment(Websites website, Comment comment, int postId)
    {
        if (await IsPostExist(postId,website))
        {
            _restClient.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri($"{website.Url}/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/");
            _restRequest.Method = Method.Post;
            _restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            _restRequest.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                post = postId,
                author_name = comment.Author,
                content = comment.Body
            });
            var result = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync(_restRequest);
            return new MessageDTO
            {
                Message = result.Content,
                Status = result.StatusCode.ToString()
            };
        }

        return new MessageDTO
        {
            Message = "Post Not Found",
            Status = "404"

        };
    }
}
```

I have a list of comments and list of products that I iterate over them and call `SendComment` method from `RestClientService` class. The problem is in first time `SendComment` method called `_restRequest` object will be get JsonBody and everything is okay but next time this method calls in loop `_restRequest` object has old data and won't be renewed.

In DI Container I added (Transient) RestClientService

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRestClientService,RestClientService>();
```

Here is where I used `SendComment` method in another service.

```
public async Task<MessageDTO> CreateSendCommentJob(SendCommentConfiguration config)
    {
        var updatedConfig = await _sendCommentConfigurationRepository.Get(config.Id);
        var ConfigDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendCommentConfigurationDetailsDTO>(updatedConfig.Configuration);
        var mappedWebsite = _mapper.Map<Websites>(ConfigDetails.WebsiteInfo);

        if (ConfigDetails.CommentType == "blog")
        {
            var comments = await _uCommentService.GetCommentsByGroupId(ConfigDetails.CommentGroupId);
            var commentCount = 0;

            
            for (int postCount = 0; postCount < ConfigDetails.ProductPerSendCount; postCount++)
            {
                var postId = ConfigDetails.Ids[postCount];

                    while (commentCount < ConfigDetails.CommentsPerProductCount)
                    {
                        var random = new Random();
                        var index = random.Next(comments.Count);

                        var result = await _restClientService.SendComment(mappedWebsite, comments[index], postId);

                        if (result.Status == "Created")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Comment Index ({index}) at Id ({postId}) submited successfuly...");
                            commentCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{postId} - {result.Status} - {result.Message}");

                        }
                    }
                ConfigDetails.Ids.Remove(postId);
                commentCount = 0;
            }

        }

        var newConfig = new SendCommentConfiguration
        {
            Id = config.Id,
            Configuration = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConfigDetails)
        };

        await _sendCommentConfigurationRepository.Edit(newConfig);

        return new MessageDTO
        {
            Status = "200",
            Message = "Comments Successfuly Sent "
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how is used the service? The loop?

Comment: @vernou Yes, I did not mention how to use it so as not to complicate the question. I edited the question and added the relevant part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_restClientService.SendComment` is called in a loop on the same service instance. As the request instance is a field of the service instance, the same request instance is **reused for each call**.

As each apple performs a distinct request, each request must use a distinct instance of `RestRequest`, like :

```cs
public class RestClientService : IRestClientService
{
    public async Task<MessageDTO> SendComment(Websites website, Comment comment, int postId)
    {
        if (await IsPostExist(postId,website))
        {
            //Each call, new instances
            var restClient = new RestClient();
            var restRequest = new RestRequest(); 

            restClient.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri($"{website.Url}/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/");
            restRequest.Method = Method.Post;
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            restRequest.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                post = postId,
                author_name = comment.Author,
                content = comment.Body
            });
            var result = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(_restRequest);
            return new MessageDTO
            {
                Message = result.Content,
                Status = result.StatusCode.ToString()
            };
        }

        return new MessageDTO
        {
            Message = "Post Not Found",
            Status = "404"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer vernou, So we can't handle this situation with a more efficient solution ?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of "efficient"?

Comment: If the number of requests increases, won't the program suffer in terms of performance? as far as I know we use dependency injection to prevent making new object from classes many times.

Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: Create a new instance is nothing. But sometime is recommended to avoid multiple instance like with `Random`. If you want improve performance, begin to avoid `new Random()`.

Comment: From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0#avoiding-multiple-instantiations) : `... can lead to performance issues, because instantiating and initializing a random number generator is a relatively expensive process`.

Comment: If you want more explanation or help to improve your code, you can ask a other question.

Comment: I could add that you should not change anything in the client options after the client is instantiated. This particular code is fine as it changes the base URL, but the ability to mutate options will be removed in RestSharp 109. The base URL is called "base" because it should be set once.